# Random length sentence using list items?

Tags: python

I want a sentence with random length between 3 to 5. I am getting list items as strings.

Here's the code (not completed):

```
my_list = ["Please", "add", "me", "to", "a", "supergroup!"]

number = random.randint(3, 6)

rand_snt = random.choices(my_list, k=number)
```

Comment: `print(' '.join(rand_snt))`

Comment: If you don't want to use the same word twice, you should use random.sample instead of random.choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. Only change the random interval and use `' '.join()`:

```py
my_list = ["Please", "add", "me", "to", "a", "supergroup!"]

number = random.randint(3, 5)

rand_snt = ' '.join(random.choices(my_list, k=number))
```

Sample output:

```py
Please a supergroup!
```

`' '.join()` concatenates items in a list using the separator on which it is applied. In this case we want them to be separated by a space, so we use `' '`.